# Python console can't deal with Unicode?

Tags: python, windows, unicode, console

(I'm using Python 3.4 for this, on Windows)

So, I have this code I whipped out to better show my troubles:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os
os.startfile('C:\\téxt.txt')
```

On IDLE it works as it should (it just opens that file I specified), but on Console (double-click) it keeps saying Windows can't find the file. Of course, if I try to open "text.txt" instead it works perfectly, as long as it exists.

It's slowly driving me insane. Someone help me, please.

Comment: Python can (especially Python 3), but your OS ans it's file system has some troubles with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the wrong encoding, try using `cp1252` -

```
# -*- coding: cp1252 -*-
```

Comment: GEE THAT WAS FAST

Thank you, it worked. I had this feeling I would never figure this out myself.

Comment: @Rafael, you should edit the file to save it as UTF-8. Code page 1252 only gives you 250 characters instead of the full range of Unicode.

Comment: @Rafael: don't do it: it fixes symptoms, not the core issue. Your original problems is that you've saved utf-8 text as cp1252. Save your Python as utf-8 as @ eryksun suggested instead.

Comment: I don't get it, isn't the code defined on the `coding:` section? I used utf-8 to no avail, as stated before, is anything missing?

Comment: @Rafael: 1. changing `coding` does not magically change the actual bytes in the file, it just changes how they interpreted: the issue is that `coding` declaration in your code lies (it specifies one encoding while another encoding is actually used in the file) -- changing `coding` works but you should change the file itself instead (copy-paste from the question and make sure your editor uses utf-8 while saving the file) 2. unrelated: you could omit `coding: utf-8` -- it is default in Python 3

Answer (score 0):

Your file name is 'C:\téxt.txt',try to use 'C:\text.txt'

Comment: The OP already stated that it was working when using `text.txt` instead of `téxt`.

Comment: @Sky The whole issue is that I might want to work with paths containing Unicode, so changing the file or folder names is the worst workaround, even though it works.